# How do I add keystroke Z to keyPressed(KeyEvent e) to jump/repaint the ball to a new random location? (KeyListener demo used.)

Tags: java, swing, jframe, keylistener, keyevent

I have limited Java experience, especially when it relates to graphics. I've had great help on this problem so far. It's starter code (at the bottom) which works fine as I tested it in Eclipse. I'm using it from a class to teach a high school student. As per the instructions below in comments, would someone know an easy way to extend the already simple program to cause the ball to jump/move/repaint to a random new location, after pressing the Z button? I'm thinking of adding the following code to the **keyPressed(KeyEvent e)** method:

```
else if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_Z)    
{     
   //Not sure what to add here. Just want to change X and Y coordinates to 
   //anything, so long as the program works and stays fairly simple  
   //for now.
   //----> g.fillOval(x + radius, y + radius, 2 * radius, 2 * radius);   
   // this line above says "g can not be resolved". 
}
```

.

Any tips or ideas to keep the program simple would be very much appreciated. Thank you!

.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;                            // #1
import javax.swing.*;   

/******************************************************************************
 * 
 * KeyListenerDemo.java
 * Demonstrates getting keyboard input using the KeyListener interface.
 * 
 * Program 18: Extend this program by adding a few more keystroke commands:
 *      z     (VK_Z)    - Cause the ball to jump to a random new location.
 *      s     (VK_S)    - Make the ball smaller - multiply its diameter 1/2.
 *      b     (VK_B)    - Make the ball bigger - multiply its diameter by 2.
 *      c     (VK_C)    - Change the color (in any way you'd like).
 *
 *  In addition, modify the program to ensure the following:
 *  - The ball goes all the way to the edge of the screen but stays
 *          completely on the screen. 
 *  - If a doubled diameter doesn't fit, make it as large as possible.
 *  - Be sure the ball never completely disappears.
 * 
 *****************************************************************************/
    public class KeyListenerDemo extends JFrame
                            implements KeyListener      // #2
    {
    // Class Scope Finals
    private static final int SCREEN_WIDTH = 1000;
    private static final int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 800;
    private static final int START_RADIUS = 25;
    private static final int START_X = 100;
    private static final int START_Y = 100;
    private static final int STEP_SIZE = 10;

    // Class Scope Variables
    private static int x = START_X;             // x at center of the ball
    private static int y = START_Y;             // y at center of the ball
    private static int radius = START_RADIUS;   // radius of the ball

    // Methods
    /**
     * Create the window and register this as a KeyListener
     * 
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        // Set up the JFrame window.
        KeyListenerDemo gp = new KeyListenerDemo();
        gp.setSize(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
        gp.setVisible(true);

        gp.addKeyListener(gp);                          // #3
        // If this class had a constructor and you moved this line into
        //   that constructor it could not refer to gp since that variable
        //   is local to this method.  Instead you would write::
        // addKeyListener(this);
    }

    /**
     * Called when a key is first pressed
     * Required for any KeyListener
     * 
     * @param e     Contains info about the key pressed
     */
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)                  // #4A
    {
        int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
        {
            x = x - STEP_SIZE;
        }
        else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
        {
            x = x + STEP_SIZE;
        }
        else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
        {
            y = y - STEP_SIZE;
        }
        else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
        {
            y = y + STEP_SIZE;
        }
        repaint();
    }

    /**
     * Called when typing of a key is completed
     * Required for any KeyListener
     * 
     * @param e     Contains info about the key typed
     */
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)                    // #4B
    {
    }

    /**
     * Called when a key is released
     * Required for any KeyListener
     * 
     * @param e     Contains info about the key released
     */
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)                 // #4C
    {
    }

    /**
     * paint - draw the figure
     * 
     * @param g     Graphics object to draw in
     */


       public void paint(Graphics g)
        {
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);

            g.setColor(Color.blue);
            g.fillOval(x - radius, y - radius, 2 * radius, 2 * radius);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The basic concept would be to change the values of the coords, then call repaint(). That method is where the `g` you talked about resides. If the problem lies with creating random coords, then check java's `Random` class.

Comment: 1- Use [key bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), thay don't suffer from the same focus related issues that `KeyListener` does. 2- Call `super.paint(g)` in your `paint` method, in fact, you really shouldn't be overriding `paint` of a top level container.

Comment: Painting should be done in the paint method, you simply need to adjust the x/y position of the object a trigger a `repaint`...

Comment: I'm not concerned with java's Random class for now. But how would I change the value of the coordinates by pressing the Z key? I was hoping to make a coordinate change from within keyPressed method. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks MadProgrammer. I wanted to make a change within an if else statement if at all possible for pressing Z. What would making use of key bindings look like? Do you have a sample? I'm looking at the link right now. Not sure how to proceed with the code I have so far that's working. Help please?

Answer (score 1):

Try doing something like this:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
if(e.getKeyCode == KeyEvent.VK_Z){

moveRand();
//Assuming that is the method for moving the ball randomly.
    }
}
```

and than

```
public void moveRand(Graphics2D g){

g.drawOval(Random.nextInt() / window.getWidth() + 1, Random.nextInt() / window.getHight() + 1, ballWidth, ballHight);


}
```

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that `g` cannot be resolved is that it does not exist in the `keyPressed()` method.  `g` is what is called a parameter of the method `paint()`.  This means that you can only refer to it within the method `paint()`.  You can declare another variable named `g` outside the method `paint()`, but it won't be the same `g`.  It won't even have to have the same type.

That said, you do not need to reference `g` directly at all in order to solve your problem.  The `paint()` method already handles drawing a circle.  You just need to change where the circle is and tell the application to repaint it.  If you assign new values to `x` and `y` and then invoke `repaint()`, the circle will move.  Notice that `repaint()` is already called at the end of the `keyPressed()` method.

Here is an example.  Replace the code on the right hand side of the equals with whatever may be appropriate to your problem.

```
else if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_Z)    
{     
   x = x + radius;
   y = y + radius;
}
```

If you look at the other if/else clauses, you will see that this is what they are doing as well.